# Can't convert .htaccess to nginx directives

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, vhosts

in order to install Taskly crm, I'm trying to convert three simple directives by an .htaccess file to nginx vhosts directives without success.

I've installed Cloudpanel on my own vps server and when i add a website it comes with pre-configured vhosts, and this is the default file i have:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name crm.mydomain.it;
  {{root}}

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name crm.mydomain.it;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    
 
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }
  
  


  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}
```

And i have those .htaccess rules to add:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js|custom)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I translated those directives into this code with an online tool, and i tried to insert those lines where i supposed i should with success, as Cloudpanel if there is a error will not allow me to save the vhosts file, but it allowed me without problem. The problem is that adding those lines make my domain cause a loop redirect error.

Translated directives:

```
# nginx configuration by winginx.com

autoindex off;

location ~* (\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.ico|\.woff|\.woff2|.ttf|\.svg)$ {
}

location ~ /public/ {
}

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /%1 redirect;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(css|assets|landing|storage|installer|js|custom)/(.*)$ /public/$1/$2 break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried to add a nginx.conf file into root of the website and place the winginx.com result in it?

Comment: Sure, and nothing happens, instead i can successfully use nginx.conf file in another website hosted in my server with cloudpanel without problem, so i suppose is a directive problem..

Comment: The directive seems legit to me

Comment: What it can be so?